# angular material stepper: disable header navigation

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to navigate the stepper only through the next and back buttons.

I can't get this to work since users can also click each step label to navigate to any step. I can't use linear, since it requires each step to have a `formArray` or `FormGroup`.

I have tried `<mat-step (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">`.

Comment: Did you have any success with finding a solution?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Add this to your style sheet. I was trying to disable the header navigation. Tried many things but this hack worked. You can try this till Angular Material Team support this feature.

```
::ng-deep .mat-horizontal-stepper-header{
    pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

Comment: This does not work, I can still navigate to previous step with the header

Comment: @Mel Kindly add this chunk of code at the end of your main style.css or style.scss. It will work

Comment: @ShahzaibShahid Why does adding it to the component's scss file not work? Why does it have to be the shared style.scss file?

Comment: @KaMok it's because we are overwriting the CSS for the specified class so it should be at the parent level so it can be overwritten.

Comment: @ShahzaibShahid You will also need to manually set the tabindex attributes of the stepper-headers to '-1' so you can't tab to the steps with a keyboard

Comment: it works if u use ng-deep:
::ng-deep .mat-horizontal-stepper-header {...}

Comment: Very usefull, just by passing by css, Thanks

Comment: Yes it works unless you are using a vertical stepper in which case its                       
           ::ng-deep .mat-vertical-stepper-header{
               pointer-events: none !important;
             }

Answer (score 76):

Use a `linear` stepper with `completed=false` steps. When the user presses your button, programattically complete the step and move to the next one.

This way you don't need to mess with CSS pointer events. In our app, that resulted in accessibility problems with NVDA.

```js
    <mat-horizontal-stepper linear #stepper>
      <mat-step completed="false">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Step 1</ng-template>
        <app-some-child (nextClicked)="nextClicked($event)" ></app-some-child>
      </mat-step>
      <mat-step>
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Step 2</ng-template>
        <app-some-other-child></app-some-other-child>
      </mat-step>
    </mat-horizontal-stepper>
    
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

      @ViewChild('stepper') stepper: MatStepper;

      nextClicked(event) {
        // complete the current step
        this.stepper.selected.completed = true;
        // move to next step
        this.stepper.next();
      }
    }
```

Comment: This is the proper way to do it.

Comment: Cool solution! Note that it will not prevent the user to go back to first step once he is at the second step (and that may be something you need)
For this you can add `editable="false"` to your `mat-step`s

Comment: Nice solution here! Thank you

Comment: Bad solution, it doesn't disable "next" steps, previous steps don't become grayed out.  Css is more right solution,

Comment: Great answer and proper way to implement

Comment: Seems obvious but if you don't set the selected step as completed the stepper won't move. If you want to disable the previous step you can also set the `this.stepper.selected.editable = false`

Answer (score 8):

Does not work without **::ng-deep**

```css
    ::ng-deep .mat-horizontal-stepper-header{
      pointer-events: none !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Don't use ::ng-deep as it is deprecated.

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Instead, if you are using Angular Material, use the theme guide from the documentation.

https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Example of a implementation of the style:

my-custom-elements.scss

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@mixin custom-stepper-theme() {
  .mat-horizontal-stepper-header {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```

global-material-theme.scss

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat-core();

@import './material/my-custom-elements.scss';

@include custom-stepper-theme();
```

angular.json

```
...
"styles": ["src/styles.scss", "src/app/global-material-theme.scss"]
...
```

Comment: How can I custom for only one component is my angular app?

Comment: Put a different class on it. And use the class specification (then you can define the mixin inside the scss of that component, its a better code practice to say it is a specific style)

Answer (score 8):

For anyone that's still looking for an alternate solution if `::ng-deep` does not work.

Furthermore, `::ng-deep` is [deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) and setting `ViewEncapsulation` to none is the preferred way to go if you want to do it using CSS.

Import `ViewEncapsulation` and set to `None` in your

**compnent.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "stepper-overview-example",
  templateUrl: "stepper-overview-example.html",
  styleUrls: ["stepper-overview-example.css"],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class StepperOverviewExample implements OnInit {
  isLinear = false;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

set `pointer-events` to `none` in your

**component.css**:

```
.mat-horizontal-stepper-header { 
  pointer-events: none !important; 
}
```

Here's a [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scrh9a).

Comment: Thank you! I had a nested stepper and the encapuslation property you mention here made all the difference (y)

Comment: ViewEncapsulation None is not a good idea. That should be reserved for the ultimate "no other possible option" scenario. The side effects will not be obvious, and you will find them in the form of bugs over a long period of time. Lots of weird issues with styles being picked up and/or applied in all the wrong places. Just do some serious spot-checking throughout your entire app before releasing it if you chose this route.

Answer (score 6):

Just to improve on the accepted answer, as it will not work if you have a vertical stepper.

To stop the user being able to click the header and navigate add the following code to you style.css file in the root:-

```
.mat-step-header {
  pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

This will ensure it works for `mat-horizontal-stepper-header` and `mat-vertical-stepper-header`

Answer (score 3):

I found a somewhat hacky solution for this. The problem is that you cannot fully disable the header navigation, but you can prevent it from being active until a certain moment.

And that moment is `form.invalid`.

My situation was the following: User needs to fill the form inside the step, press 'save' and only then be able to use `NEXT` button and navigate the stepper further (also back).

What I did was introduce another `hidden` `input` which would be using angular's `[required]` dynamic attribute. It will only be `required` if the previous `save` condition wasn't successful. Once it succeeds this field won't be `required` and user can navigate further.

Together with mat-stepper (or md-stepper) attribute `editable` you should be able to achieve what you want.

Let me know if you fully understood the idea.

Answer (score 2):

This also did the trick for me

**Requirement:**

- Allow navigation either from Navigation or Next Button only WHEN `form` is valid
- Disabled Header navigation and keep button disabled till form is not valid.

```html
 <mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper [linear]="true">

    <!----------------------------->
    <!---- STEP: 1:---->
    <!----------------------------->

    <mat-step #generalStep [completed]="formGroup1.valid">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Step-1</ng-template>
      
      <form [formGroup]="formGroup1">

      // STEP-1 Content
      // matInput - with form control bindings

       <div class="container">
          <button mat-raised-button matStepperNext color="primary"[disabled]="!formGroup1.valid">Next Step</button>
        </div>

      </form>

    </mat-step>

    <!------------------------------->
    <!-- STEP: 2:-->
    <!------------------------------->


    <mat-step #generalStep [completed]="formGroup2.valid">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Step-2</ng-template>

      <form [formGroup]="formGroup2">

      // STEP-2 Content
      // matInput - with form control bindings

      <button mat-raised-button matStepperNext color="primary"[disabled]="!formGroup.valid">Next Step</button>

      </form>
    </mat-step>

  
  </mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

- FormGroup/FormControl initialization
- Adding Validators

```js
  formGroup1: FormGroup;
  formGroup2: FormGroup;

   this.formGroup1 = this.formBuilder.group({
      control1: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      control2: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    });

  this.formGroup2 = this.formBuilder.group({
    control3: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    control4: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Following works for me with click on `previous` step enabled:

```
::ng-deep .mat-vertical-stepper-header:not([ng-reflect-active="true"]){
    pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

For horizontal stepper do this:

```
::ng-deep .mat-horizontal-stepper-header:not([ng-reflect-active="true"]){
        pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need add **`ViewEncapsulation.None`** in your component config

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-example',
 encapsulation: `ViewEncapsulation.None`
 })
```

Then add this in your component CSS.

```
.mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container  {
  display: none !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, for now, the good way is to get the matStepper by a ViewChild and in the afterViewInit, add pointer-events style to none for each header.

```
@ViewChild('matStepper') matStepper: MatStepper;

...

ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.matStepper._stepHeader.forEach((x) => {
      x._elementRef.nativeElement.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
   });
}
```

This solution avoid not recommended ::ng-deep or ViewEncapsulation

Comment: that's helped me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
// so that the User cannot go directly to step 3
.mat-step-header.mat-accent[ng-reflect-index="2"] {
  pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

This is preventing the Users to go to step 3 from a 3 steps stepper.
Change the index accordingly for your project, meaning that if you want to disable step 5, make the index equal to 4. Also, put this in some sort of a Material Overrides file, or directly in your `styles.scss` file.

Answer (score -1):

Here `::ng-deep .mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container {
        display: none ;
      }`

Use this on your style sheet to remove stepper header...Like Step-1,Step-2

Answer (score -4):

You need to add an "linear" attribute (This will disable navigation)

`<mat-vertical-stepper linear>`

Comment: cause error `Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined`  when clicking next and back buttons, or the header labels. To use `linear` means to add forms which is the basic idea of the stepper... but I don't need a form for each step

Answer (score -4):

In the  tag add [linear]="true"

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper labelPostion="botton" [linear]="true">
...
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```